# Single change to query, vastly increased execution time

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-optimization

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(SFRSTCR_CREDIT_HR) AS NUM_CREDIT_HRS, COUNT(SFRSTCR_PIDM) OVER(PARTITION BY SUM(SFRSTCR_CREDIT_HR)) AS NUM_STUDENTS
FROM SATURN.SFRSTCR 
WHERE SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '&TermCode'
  AND SFRSTCR_PIDM IN(SELECT DISTINCT SPRIDEN_PIDM
                      FROM SATURN.SPRIDEN, SATURN.SGBSTDN ta1, SATURN.SFRSTCR
                      WHERE SPRIDEN_PIDM = ta1.SGBSTDN_PIDM 
                        AND SPRIDEN_PIDM = SFRSTCR_PIDM
                        AND ta1.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = (SELECT MAX(ta2.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF)
                                                         FROM SATURN.SGBSTDN ta2
                                                         WHERE ta1.SGBSTDN_PIDM = ta2.SGBSTDN_PIDM)
                        AND ta1.SGBSTDN_STST_CODE = 'AS'
                        AND ta1.SGBSTDN_LEVL_CODE = 'US' 
                        AND ta1.SGBSTDN_RESD_CODE = 'R' 
                        AND SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND IS NULL 
                        AND SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '&TermCode' 
                        AND (SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE LIKE 'R%'
                         OR  SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE LIKE 'W%')
                        AND SFRSTCR_CREDIT_HR >= 1) 
  AND SFRSTCR_PIDM NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT SFRSTCR_PIDM 
                          FROM SATURN.SFRSTCR, SATURN.SSBSECT
                          WHERE SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
                            AND SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT_CRN
                            AND SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '&TermCode' 
                            AND (SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE LIKE 'R%'
                             OR  SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE LIKE 'W%')
                            AND SFRSTCR_CREDIT_HR >= 1 
                          GROUP BY SFRSTCR_PIDM
                          HAVING MAX(SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB) LIKE '0%') 
GROUP BY SFRSTCR_PIDM
HAVING SUM(SFRSTCR_CREDIT_HR) >=1
ORDER BY NUM_CREDIT_HRS
```

This query takes 5 seconds to execute. However, if I change the line `AND ta1.SGBSTDN_RESD_CODE = 'R'` to `AND ta1.SGBSTDN_RESD_CODE = 'N'`, the execution time increases to 1 hour and 45 minutes. 'N' is also a valid value in SGBSTDN_RESD_CODE, and if anything there should be fewer 'N' values than 'R' values.

The database is Oracle. Does anyone know why this behavior might occur?

Edit: Explain plans appear to be identical.

With 'R':
Plan

```
1 One or more rows were retrieved using index SATURN.PK_SGBSTDN .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
2 The rows were sorted in order to be grouped.
3 A view definition was processed, either from a stored view SYS.VW_SQ_1  or as defined by steps 2.
4 Rows were retrieved using the unique index SATURN.PK_SGBSTDN .
5 Rows from table SATURN.SGBSTDN  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
6 For each row retrieved by step 3, the operation in step 5 was performed to find a matching row.
7 One or more rows were retrieved using index SATURN.SPRIDEN_PIDM_INDEX .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
8 For each row retrieved by step 6, the operation in step 7 was performed to find a matching row.
9 One or more rows were retrieved using index SATURN.SFRSTCR_KEY_INDEX3 .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
10 For each row retrieved by step 8, the operation in step 9 was performed to find a matching row.
11 Rows from table SATURN.SFRSTCR  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
12 For each row retrieved by step 10, the operation in step 11 was performed to find a matching row.
13 One or more rows were retrieved using index SATURN.PK_SFRSTCR .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
14 Rows from table SATURN.SFRSTCR  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
15 Rows were retrieved using the unique index SATURN.PK_SSBSECT .
16 For each row retrieved by step 14, the operation in step 15 was performed to find a matching row.
17 Rows from table SATURN.SSBSECT  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
18 For each row retrieved by step 16, the operation in step 17 was performed to find a matching row.
19 SORT GROUP BY NOSORT
20 For the rows returned by step 19, filter out rows depending on filter criteria.
21 One or more rows were retrieved using index SATURN.PK_SFRSTCR .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
22 Rows from table SATURN.SFRSTCR  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
23 SORT GROUP BY NOSORT
24 WINDOW SORT
25 The rows from step 24 were sorted to eliminate duplicate rows.
26 Rows were returned by the SELECT statement.
```

With 'N'
Plan

```
1 One or more rows were retrieved using index SATURN.PK_SGBSTDN .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
2 The rows were sorted in order to be grouped.
3 A view definition was processed, either from a stored view SYS.VW_SQ_1  or as defined by steps 2.
4 Rows were retrieved using the unique index SATURN.PK_SGBSTDN .
5 Rows from table SATURN.SGBSTDN  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
6 For each row retrieved by step 3, the operation in step 5 was performed to find a matching row.
7 One or more rows were retrieved using index SATURN.SPRIDEN_PIDM_INDEX .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
8 For each row retrieved by step 6, the operation in step 7 was performed to find a matching row.
9 One or more rows were retrieved using index SATURN.SFRSTCR_KEY_INDEX3 .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
10 For each row retrieved by step 8, the operation in step 9 was performed to find a matching row.
11 Rows from table SATURN.SFRSTCR  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
12 For each row retrieved by step 10, the operation in step 11 was performed to find a matching row.
13 One or more rows were retrieved using index SATURN.PK_SFRSTCR .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
14 Rows from table SATURN.SFRSTCR  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
15 Rows were retrieved using the unique index SATURN.PK_SSBSECT .
16 For each row retrieved by step 14, the operation in step 15 was performed to find a matching row.
17 Rows from table SATURN.SSBSECT  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
18 For each row retrieved by step 16, the operation in step 17 was performed to find a matching row.
19 SORT GROUP BY NOSORT
20 For the rows returned by step 19, filter out rows depending on filter criteria.
21 One or more rows were retrieved using index SATURN.PK_SFRSTCR .  The index was scanned in ascending order..
22 Rows from table SATURN.SFRSTCR  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
23 SORT GROUP BY NOSORT
24 WINDOW SORT
25 The rows from step 24 were sorted to eliminate duplicate rows.
26 Rows were returned by the SELECT statement.
```

Comment: What are the two query plans?  Are statistics up to date?  Is there a histogram on `sgbstdn_resd_code`?  Is that histogram accurate?

Comment: Have you checked the execution plans of each of the queries? Play spot the difference with your execution plans, and you should find out where the additional time is coming from. The different (less efficient) execution plan could be a product of out of date statistics

Comment: Not related to your exact question, but "not in (subqery)" is slow.  You can speed that part up by using "not exists" or, "in (select somefield minus select the same field where you want to exclude it)"

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: @DanBracuk `NOT IN` is no less efficient than `NOT EXISTS`, it is different in that if there are null values in the subquery then no results will be returned when using `NOT IN`, but assuming there are no null values in the subquery both are exactly the same, and both use the `ANTI SEMI JOIN`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm just researcher writing queries against the database, not a DBA, so I can't answer some of your questions. SGBSTDN_RESD_CODE does not appear to be indexed. As far as I can tell, only SGBSTDN_PIDM and SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF are indexed and form the primary key.

Comment: @anbisme what tool do you use to get execution plan?

Comment: @be here now I am using Toad.

Comment: @anbisme I'd suggest you to use `dbms_xplan.display[_cursor]` function output (or even to query actual v$sqlplan data) as a tool to get query execution plan. It may seem to be difficult to understand at first, however, it graphically represents hierarchical nature of the plan and is way more conventional. The plaintext output you provided ( For each row  ... Rows from table ...  For each row ) is pretty much unreadable, IMO.

Comment: @be here now I tried but I don't have the proper permissions.

Answer (score -1):

I would try adding an index on the SGBSTDN_RESD_CODE column